# Is there any utility in java 8 which can calculate the number of days or minutes or years between two dates?

Tags: date, time, calendar, java-8

What is the best way to calculate the number of year or days or minutes between two dates?

I got many search results but none of them answered the question using java 8 utility.

I know we can get a difference between the milis of both the days and then do calculation on the difference as follows:

```
 System.currentTimeMillis() - oldDate.getTime()
```

But is there any other way to do this? Any java 8 way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using java.time.LocalDateTime and java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit. ChronoUnit provides the between() method which can be used for these kind of requirements.
The following code snippet helped me out with the solution:

```
    LocalDateTime timeNow = LocalDateTime.now();
    LocalDateTime timeAfterSometime = timeNow.plusHours(4).plusMinutes(11);

    System.out.println("timeNow = "+timeNow);
    System.out.println("timeAfterSometime = "+timeAfterSometime);

    long minutesDiff = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(timeNow, timeAfterSometime); // 251
    long hoursDiff = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(timeNow, timeAfterSometime); // 4

    System.out.println("minutesDiff = "+minutesDiff);
    System.out.println("hoursDiff = "+hoursDiff);
```

The output was as desired as follows:

```
timeNow = 2016-12-07T15:20:11.022
timeAfterSometime = 2016-12-07T19:31:11.022
minutesDiff = 251
hoursDiff = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try out java.time.period class. You can create a period object using two dates, and period.getDays() will give you number of days, similarly getYears(), getMonths() etc.

```
enter code here
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDateTime toDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2014, 9, 9, 19, 46, 45);
    LocalDateTime fromDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(1984, 12, 16, 7, 45, 55);
    Period period = Period.between(dob.toLocalDate(), now.toLocalDate());
    long time[] = getTime(fromDateTime, toDateTime);
    System.out.println(period.getYears() + " years " + 
            period.getMonths() + " months " + 
            period.getDays() + " days " +
            time[0] + " hours " +
            time[1] + " minutes " +
            time[2] + " seconds.");


}
enter code here


private static long[] getTime(LocalDateTime dob, LocalDateTime now) {
        LocalDateTime today = LocalDateTime.of(now.getYear(),
                now.getMonthValue(), now.getDayOfMonth(), dob.getHour(), dob.getMinute(), dob.getSecond());
        Duration duration = Duration.between(today, now);

        long seconds = duration.getSeconds();

        long hours = seconds / SECONDS_PER_HOUR;
        long minutes = ((seconds % SECONDS_PER_HOUR) / SECONDS_PER_MINUTE);
        long secs = (seconds % SECONDS_PER_MINUTE);

        return new long[]{hours, minutes, secs};
    }
```

Comment: But how would I get the difference between two? Any code snippet from your side?

Comment: LocalDateTime toDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2014, 9, 9, 19, 46, 45);
        LocalDateTime fromDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(1984, 12, 16, 7, 45, 55);

        Period period = getPeriod(fromDateTime, toDateTime);
        long time[] = getTime(fromDateTime, toDateTime);

        System.out.println(period.getYears() + " years " + 
                period.getMonths() + " months " + 
                period.getDays() + " days " +
                time[0] + " hours " +
                time[1] + " minutes " +
                time[2] + " seconds.");


    }